# Endpoint is weird Amazon Textract Python

Tags: python, amazon-textract

I'm trying to use textract in python. I got the code from this url: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-textract-code-samples/blob/c8f34ca25113100730e0f4db3f6f316b0cff44d6/python/02-detect-text-s3.py.
I only changed `s3BucketName` and `documentName` in the code. But when I ran the code, I got this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://textract.USA.amazonaws.com/"
```

Should I alter the url manually? If so, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint URL depends on your AWS region; `USA` is not a valid AWS region.

You can set the region when creating the boto3 client:

```
textract = boto3.client('textract', region_name='us-west-1')
```

will use https://textract.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/ as the endpoint.

Alternatively, the region can come from the profile or environment; see the [boto3 configuration docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html#configuration) for more details.